# how to merge huge amount of files without creating a new file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to merge a huge amount of files which total size is 75Gb. If I use, e.g.

`~$ cat * > out.merge`

The size of the two files amounts to 150Gb and my HD has not such space. So how to avoid duplicate the data?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: cat two files at a time, delete them afterwards?

Comment: Is it not possible to do it all at once? Probably `cat`ing batches will be very slow..

Comment: You wouldn't *want* to do this without temporary duplication, as you risk losing data if something were to go wrong half-way through.

Comment: Hi.. all options seem to be useful, specially those considering data integrity. However, I have now `too long argument list` error.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a loop for that:

```
for n in *
do
  cat "$n" >>out.merge && rm "$n"
done
```

In this case the loop erases the used file before moving on to the next one. You could even rename the first file as `out.merge` and then append the rest of them to save the space of that first one...

Comment: I would be inclined to only remove the file if the `cat` was a success - i.e. put a `&&` between `cat` and `rm`.

Comment: Also, this will misbehave if filenames contain spaces or can be evaluated as globs. It really should be `cat "$n"` and `rm "$n"`. It'd probably also be wise to explicitly skip `out.merge` as an input file; GNU `cat` checks for its input and output being the same place, but not all implementations are as robust.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I have left out the explicit check for the existence of `out.merge` for the sake of clarity. I am assuming that `out.merge` does not exist to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `cat`ing each file and removing it immediately like

```
for f in ./*; do cat "$f" && rm "$f"; done > another_dir/out.merge
```

though that will still spawn a new `cat` for each file.

Comment: You don't need the braces; the `for` loop itself can have an output redirection.

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that if you start getting errors halfway through, you might remove a file without confirming it has been successfully written to `out.merge`.

Comment: `cat "$f" && rm "$f"`

Comment: @123 That just confirms that `cat` ran successfully, not that `out.merge` is (eventually) closed successfully.

Comment: `for f in ./*; do if cat "$f" >> another_dir/out.merge; then rm "$f"; else break; fi; done` would probably be safer.